# Write BNF grammar for an XML

Tags: bnf

I would like to write a BNF grammar for an XML program, but I have some problems. I'm trying to write the rules for two elements, `Worksheet` and `Table`. `Worksheet` has optional `Table` elements, required characteristic `Name` and optional characteristic `Protected`. On the other side, `Table` has optional `Column` and `Row` elements, which have to appear with this sequence if both exist and optional characteristics `ExpandedColCount`,`ExpandedRowCount` and `StyleID`.
My rules are these:

```
Worksheet ::= Name Worksheet
            | Name Protected Worksheet
            | Worksheet Table Worksheet
            | Protected Name Worksheet
            |
            ;

Table ::= ExpandedColumnCount Table
        | ExpandedRowCount Table
        | StyleId Table
        | Column Row Table
        | Column Table
        | Row Table
        |
        ;
```

The problem is that the first rule also accepts `Table`,`Table Name` and the second rule accepts `Row Column`, `Column StyleID`. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Why do you event want to do this? XML has DTD and schema standards for this.

Comment: Cause I have a project where I have to give an XML file and write a parser to check the syntax, with Flex and Bison.

Comment: Why not just use tool that performs schema or DTD validation?

Comment: I'd start by refactoring your grammar, especially with respect to matching the empty sequence. As it is, your grammar also allows for something like `Name Protected Name Protected Name`. List everything as explicitly as possible, then reduce things slowly, checking for ambiguities. For example, `NorP ::= Name | Name Protected | Protected Name ;` eliminates the `Name` and `Protected` issue. Then you'd just need to deal with something like `Worksheet ::= NorP Table | Worksheet NorP Table;` assuming your grammar is anywhere close to what you're wanting.

Comment: I think your main problem is the fact that you're using repetition where in a way that makes the grammar ambiguous. For example, `Table ::= StyleId Table` allows for `StyleId StyleId StyleId StyleId StyleId StyleId`, and the empty sequences allow that to be the only thing listed!

Comment: Dear @ChronoKitsune thanks for the advice. I think I understood what you say.